# Is EC2 bandwidth full duplex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-ec2, duplex

Amazon documents the network speed of each instance type, giving it a rating like "25 Gbps". As long as [certain restrictions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-network-bandwidth.html) are avoided, one can largely expect to achieve this bandwidth between hosts in the same region.

My question is, is this bandwidth full-duplex? Can I get 25 Gbps in both directions between two hosts documented as having 25 Gbps network limits?

Comment: Yes, it is using gigabit-speed Ethernet connections applies in both directions.

Comment: Still looking for a "Any reference, benchmark or other reliable source would be great." or AWS docs are not enough?

Comment: @Marcin - the docs would be enough but your answer isn't conclusive in that respect if that's what you're getting at.

Answer (score 0):

If you place instances in a [cluster placement group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html), the traffic is full duplex. From [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/):

> Inter instance traffic within the **same region** can utilize up to 5 Gbps for single-flow and up to 100 Gbps for multi-flow traffic in each direction (**full duplex**).

> Network traffic to the Internet is limited to 5 Gbps (**full duplex**).

If the instances are not in a cluster, then the AWS docs do not specify if network traffic is full duplex or not. Thus, one can assume its not in that case.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was voted -1. Instances have aggregate bandwidth between other instances in the same region, and only full duplex in the cluster placement group. I've confirmed this from the docs + an AWS support agent. Here's information specific to ENA: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-network-performance-ena.html

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to indicate this is not full-duplex. in the aws doc [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-network-bandwidth.html)
, assuming you do not exceed the limits for the VM cpu type, or number of connections etc.

Timing from a one way copy

```
time scp WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home.zip ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-80:~
WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home.zip

100% 1376MB 101.2MB/s   00:13    

real    0m13.809s
user    0m3.210s
sys 0m2.786s
```

timing from simultaneous copy of the same file - to each other VM

```
time scp WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home.zip ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-80:/tmp
WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home.zip                                                                                                                    100% 1376MB  91.0MB/s   00:15    

real    0m15.675s
user    0m3.376s
sys 0m2.969s

time scp WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home.zip ubuntu@ip-172-31-24-217:/tmp
WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home.zip                                                                                                                                              100% 1376MB  98.3MB/s   00:13    

real    0m14.242s
user    0m3.381s
sys 0m3.134s
```

Thus both way, simultaneous copy speed is very close to one way copy speed.
Both were t2.medium machine - which is rated to be "upto 1 GBps" from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/general-purpose-instances.html#general-purpose-network-performance)
but for such a small 1.4 GB file it did not get a time to peak bandwidth usage. Hope this helps